# Selenium ChromeDriver - is it possible to load multiple extensions?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromium, chrome-options

(I'm new so don't kill me, please)

I'm trying to start ChromeDriver for a Chromium-based browser with multiple unpacked extensions, thus (simplified for your convenience, but basically the same as in the code):

```
   foreach (var path in ExtensionsPaths)
   {
    CommonWebDriver._ChromeOptionsForTorch.AddArguments(new string[1] { "--load-extension=" + path });
   }
```

After the foreach finishes running, I see all the extensions I want to load listed in the options.

When I create the ChromeDriver, though, **it only loads one extension from this list - the last one of them**.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to load multiple extensions?

Comment: I love the reputation Stackoverflow has gotten :P seen so clearly here. Welcome, as long as you read how to post a question I'm pretty sure no one will try to kill you :P

Comment: Thanks! Right now I'm hiding under my desk, sword in hand. Just in case, you know. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

foreach (var path in ExtensionsPaths)
{
    options.AddExtensions(new File(path));
}
```

Comment: Isn't this for packed CRXs?

Comment: This works for extensions packed by zip. Did not try this for CRX.

Answer (score 1):

You provide one argument string containing multiple paths to extensions separated by comma:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument(@"load-extension=c:\PathToFirstExtensionHere,c:\PathToSecondExtensionHere");
Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: In my case this does not work for extensions packed by zip. But using ChromeOptions.AddExtensions in cycle work fine. chromedriver 78.0.3904.10500.